# fs existsSync() Works on Localhost but Not on Digital Ocean Droplet

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, web, digital-ocean

I am currently developing a Node application that runs on a Digital Ocean droplet. The application takes a `post` request from the user (through another application that is connected to the website), in order to upload a file. I am doing this through the Node fs extension. The code inside the `post` request handler reads

```
        var fileNameOrginalIndexArray = fileNameOriginal.split("\\");
        fileNameOriginalAttempt1 = fileNameOrginalIndexArray.join("/");// C:
        fileNameOriginalAttempt2 = 
            "/mnt/" + fileNameOrginalIndexArray[0].charAt(0).toLowerCase() + "/"
            + fileNameOrginalIndexArray.slice(1, fileNameOrginalIndexArray.length).join("/");// /mnt/c
        if(fs.existsSync(fileNameOriginalAttempt1)){
            fs.createReadStream(fileNameOriginalAttempt1).pipe(streamwrite);
        }
        else if(fs.existsSync(fileNameOriginalAttempt2)){
            fs.createReadStream(fileNameOriginalAttempt2).pipe(streamwrite);
        }
        else{
            res.send("ROOM IMAGE POST ERROR");
        }
```

It is looking for the requested file in the `C:\` directory, as well as in `/mnt/c/`. Now, this whole checking-to-see-if-the-file-exists operation works perfectly lovely when I am running the application on localhost; but when I run the application through my Digital Ocean droplet, it says that the files do not exist.

I suspect this has something to do with it checking my local computer when it's running on localhost, as opposed to running on the server; but I am frankly quite clueless to why this is happening. Would someone be able to tell me why my files are found with fs when running the app on localhost, but not when running the app on a Digital Ocean droplet? Thanks in advance!

Comment: At the very least, start using [path.join](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) and related functions, instead of using string splitting/concatenation. `path` guarantees correct path strings, whereas hand rolled strings basically guarantee bugs =)

Comment: My guess is that the pathnames are different on the droplet, and you're not using the correct paths.